# I'm running the follow code but it's showing me error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I tried to create my own AI Virtual Assistant but when i run the code it popup with an error
This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DUCHESS PATSY\OneDrive\Desktop\MyJarvisProject\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DUCHESS PATSY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DUCHESS PATSY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DUCHESS PATSY\OneDrive\Desktop\MyJarvisProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError():
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

I coded this to test my Speech Recognition. Here is the code

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

while True:

    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:

            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

            text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio)
            text = text.lower()

            print(f"Recognized {text}")

    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError():

        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        continue
```

Comment: What happens if you change `UnknownValueError()` to `UnknownValueError`?

Comment: Looks like you might be catching the wrong exception. Have you tried using `except:` instead of `except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError():` so it handles exceptions generally?

Also, it seems like you're creating an infinite loop with `while True:` – I'm not sure whether that's the intention. And be aware that it's generally difficult to debut with try/except clauses since they tend to ignore exceptions.

Comment: I tried but showing same error